# ID column panel data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
Municipalities   Year   Emissions
Adamantina       2010       540
Adamantina       2011       543
Adamantina       2012       580
Adolfo           2010       410
Adolfo           2011       411
Adolfo           2012       432
```

I would like to assign an ID to each observation having the same Municipalitie name ranging from 1 to n. This would result in the following table:

```
Municipalities   Year   Emissions   id
Adamantina       2010       540      1
Adamantina       2011       543      1
Adamantina       2012       580      1
Adolfo           2010       410      2
Adolfo           2011       411      2
Adolfo           2012       432      2
```

How can I do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.table`. Following code assumes your dataframe is named `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, id := .GRP, by = Municipalities]
```